# How to use Makefiles with R CMD build

Tags: r, makefile

I am developing a R package.  It is based on a project that only used Makefile.  Most of it easily translated to the `R CMD build` workflow. However the pdfs I need to create are a bit complex and I don't get them right unless I tinker - so far I figured how to do it with a Makefile.

In the R package documentations I find references to use Makefiles for [sources](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#make) and even [for vignettes](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_21.html).

I don't grasp how these should be applied. From these documentations I had the impression Makefiles would be called in the process of `R CMD build` but when I put Makefile in the described directories they are just ignored. However `R CMD check` recognises them and outputs passing tests.

I also have seen some Makefiles that call `R CMD build` inside - but I keep wondering how these would execute when I use `install.packages`.   That doesn't seem right - I mean why would `R CMD check` these if it wouldn't care about.  And there's also this [page in R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html) about adding `SystemRequiremens: GNU make` - why do this for a file you don't use?

So what is the best practice nowadays? And are there examples in the wild that I can look at?

**Updates**

*As I was asked for an example*

I want to build a vignette as similar as described in ["Writing package vignettes"](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_21.html).  There is a master Latex file which includes several Rnw files.
The concrete dilemmas are:

1. how do I build the pdf vignette?
2. how can I enforce dependencies — obviously the rnws need to rendered first
3. the Rnw need slowly calculated data that is neither intended to go into the package nor in the repo (it's some gigabytes) — but it is reused several times during the build.

So far I do it with a Makefile, the general pattern is like this:

```
tmp/test.pdf: tmp/test.tex tmp/rnw1.tex tmp/rnw2.tex
    latexmk -outdir=$(@D) $<

tmp/%.tex: r/%.rnw
    Rscript -e "knitr::knit('$<', output='$@')"

tmp/rnw1.tex tmp/rnw2.tex: tmp/slowdata.Rdata

tmp/slowdata.Rdata: r/ireallytakeforever.R
    Rscript $<
```

Comment: From what I understand, I think you can set compiler flags, or even set a different compiler like gcc vs clang++ (if you need it), but I'm not sure if this should be best practice.

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible sample package that demonstrates the dilemma?

Comment: Reproducible is hard in this case as I only know how to do it with an makefile.  But I spelled out  my dilemmas.

Comment: @bdecaf - No worries, I deleted my answer. You stated "The question is how Makefiles and the package build workflow are supposed to go together" - that requires a different answer. Take care.

Answer (score 19):

Bdecaf,

Ok, answer version 2.0 - chuckle.

You mentioned that "*The question is how Makefiles and the package build workflow are supposed to go together*". In that context, my recommendation is you review a set of example R package makefiles:

- [Makefile](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/Makefile) for [Yihui Xie](http://yihui.name/)'s [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) package for [R](http://r-project.org/).
- [Makefile](https://github.com/kbroman/qtlcharts/blob/master/Makefile) for my [R/qtlcharts](https://github.com/kbroman/qtlcharts) package.

The `knitr` package `makefile` (in my view) provides a good example of how to build vignettes. You need to review the `makefile` and directory structure,  that would be the template I would recommend you review and use.

I'd also recommend you look at [maker](https://github.com/ComputationalProteomicsUnit/maker), a Makefile for R package development. On top of this, I would start with [Karl Broman](https://github.com/kbroman) guides - (this is what I used myself as a source reference a while back now eclipsed by Hadley's book on packages but still useful (in my view).

- ***Minimal make: A minimal tutorial on Make***
- ***R package Primer***.

The other recommendation is to read Rob Hynman's article I referenced previously

- [Makefiles for R/LaTeX projects](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/makefiles/)

between them, you should be able to do what you request. Above and beyond that you have the base R package manual you referenced.

I hope the above helps.

T.

---

## Referenced pages:

### [minimal make A minimal tutorial on make](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://kbroman.org/minimal_make/) - Author **Karl Broman**

I would argue that the most important tool for reproducible research is not [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/%7Eleisch/Sweave/) or [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) but [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make).

Consider, for example, all of the files associated with a manuscript. In the simplest case, I would have an [R](http://r-project.org/) script for each figure plus a [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) file for the main text. And then a [BibTeX](http://www.bibtex.org/) file for the references.

Compiling the final PDF is a bit of work:

- Run each R script through R to produce the relevant figure.
- Run latex and then bibtex and then latex a couple of more times.

And the R scripts need to be run before latex is, and only if they’ve changed.

### A simple example

[GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make) makes this easy. In your directory for the manuscript, you create a text file called Makefile that looks something like [the following](https://github.com/Technophobe01/minimal_make/blob/gh-pages/examples/ex1/Makefile) (here using [pdflatex](http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/)).

```
mypaper.pdf: mypaper.bib mypaper.tex Figs/fig1.pdf Figs/fig2.pdf
    pdflatex mypaper
    bibtex mypaper
    pdflatex mypaper
    pdflatex mypaper

Figs/fig1.pdf: R/fig1.R
    cd R;R CMD BATCH fig1.R

Figs/fig2.pdf: R/fig2.R
    cd R;R CMD BATCH fig2.R
```

Each batch of lines indicates a file to be created (the target), the files it depends on (the prerequisites), and then a set of commands needed to construct the target from the dependent files. Note that the lines with the commands must start with a **tab** character (**not spaces**).

Another great feature: in the example above, you’d only build fig1.pdf when fig1.R changed. And note that the dependencies propagate. If you change fig1.R, then fig1.pdf will change, and so mypaper.pdf will be re-built.

**One oddity**: if you need to change directories to run a command, do the cd on the same line as the related command. The following would not work:

```
### this doesn't work ###
Figs/fig1.pdf: R/fig1.R
    cd R
    R CMD BATCH fig1.R
You can, however, use \ for a continuation line, line so:

### this works ###
Figs/fig1.pdf: R/fig1.R
    cd R;\
    R CMD BATCH fig1.R
```

Note that you still need to use the semicolon (;).

### Using GNU make

You probably already have GNU make installed on your computer. Type make --version in a terminal/shell to see. ([On Windows, go here to download make.](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm))

To use make:

- Go into the the directory for your project.
- Create the Makefile file.
- Every time you want to build the project, type make.
- In the example above, if you want to build fig1.pdf without building mypaper.pdf, just type make fig1.pdf.

#### Frills

You can go a long way with just simple make files as above, specifying the target files, their dependencies, and the commands to create them. But there are a lot of frills you can add, to save some typing.

Here are some of the options that I use. (See the [make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for further details.)

#### Variables

If you’ll be repeating the same piece of code multiple times, you might want to define a variable.

For example, you might want to run R with the flag --vanilla. You could then define a variable R_OPTS:

R_OPTS=--vanilla
You refer to this variable as $(R_OPTS) (or ${R_OPTS}; either parentheses or curly braces is allowed), so in the R commands you would use something like

cd R;R CMD BATCH $(R_OPTS) fig1.R
An advantage of this is that you just need to type out the options you want once; if you change your mind about the R options you want to use, you just have to change them in the one place.

For example, I actually like to use the following:

R_OPTS=--no-save --no-restore --no-init-file --no-site-file
This is like --vanilla but without --no-environ (which I need because I use the .Renviron file to define R_LIBS, to say that I have R packages defined in an alternative directory).

### Automatic variables

There are a bunch of automatic variables that you can use to save yourself a lot of typing. Here are the ones that I use most:

```
$@    the file name of the target
$<    the name of the first prerequisite (i.e., dependency)
$^    the names of all prerequisites (i.e., dependencies)
$(@D)    the directory part of the target
$(@F)    the file part of the target
$(<D)    the directory part of the first prerequisite (i.e., dependency)
$(<F)    the file part of the first prerequisite (i.e., dependency)
```

For example, in our simple example, we could simplify the lines

```
Figs/fig1.pdf: R/fig1.R
    cd R;R CMD BATCH fig1.R
```

We could instead write

```
Figs/fig1.pdf: R/fig1.R
    cd $(<D);R CMD BATCH $(<F)
```

The automatic variable `$(<D)` will take the value of the directory of the first prerequisite, R in this case. `$(<F)` will take value of the file part of the first prerequisite, `fig1.R` in this case.

Okay, that’s not really a simplification. There doesn’t seem to be much advantage to this, unless perhaps the directory were an obnoxiously long string and we wanted to avoid having to type it twice. The main advantage comes in the next section.

#### Pattern rules

If a number of files are to be built in the same way, you may want to use a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules). The key idea is that you can use the symbol % as a wildcard, to be expanded to any string of text.

For example, our two figures are being built in basically the same way. We could simplify the example by including one set of lines covering both fig1.pdf and fig2.pdf:

```
Figs/%.pdf: R/%.R
    cd $(<D);R CMD BATCH $(<F)
```

This saves typing and makes the file easier to maintain and extend. If you want to add a third figure, you just add it as another dependency (i.e., prerequisite) for mypaper.pdf.

Our example, with the frills

Adding all of this together, here’s what our example Makefile will [look like](https://github.com/Technophobe01/minimal_make/blob/gh-pages/examples/ex2/Makefile).

```
R_OPTS=--vanilla

mypaper.pdf: mypaper.bib mypaper.tex Figs/fig1.pdf Figs/fig2.pdf
    pdflatex mypaper
    bibtex mypaper
    pdflatex mypaper
    pdflatex mypaper

Figs/%.pdf: R/%.R
    cd $(<D);R CMD BATCH $(R_OPTS) $(<F)
```

The advantage of the added frills: less typing, and it’s easier to extend to include additional figures. The disadvantage: it’s harder for others who are less familiar with [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to understand what it’s doing.

More complicated examples

There are complicated Makefiles all over the place. Poke around github and study them.

Here are some of my own examples:

- [Makefile](https://github.com/kbroman/ailProbPaper/blob/master/Makefile) for my [AIL probabilities paper](http://www.g3journal.org/content/2/2/199.long)
- [Makefile](https://github.com/kbroman/phyloQTLpaper/blob/master/Makefile) for my [phylo QTL paper](http://www.genetics.org/content/192/1/267.full)
- [Makefile](https://github.com/kbroman/preCCProbPaper/blob/master/Makefile) for my [pre-CC probabilities paper](http://www.genetics.org/content/190/2/403.full)
- [Makefile](https://github.com/kbroman/Talk_InteractiveGraphs1/blob/master/Makefile) for a [talk on interactive graphs](http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/%7Ekbroman/talks/InteractiveGraphs/).
- [Makefile](https://github.com/kbroman/Talk_FunQTL/blob/master/Makefile) for a [talk on QTL mapping for function-valued
  traits](http://www.biostat.wisc.edu/%7Ekbroman/talks/FunQTL/).
- [Makefile](https://github.com/kbroman/qtlcharts/blob/master/Makefile) for my [R/qtlcharts package](http://kbroman.org/qtlcharts).

And here are some examples from Mike Bostock:

- [Makefile](https://github.com/mbostock/us-rivers/blob/master/Makefile) for [us-rivers](https://github.com/mbostock/us-rivers)
- [Makefile](https://github.com/mbostock/protovis/blob/master/Makefile) for [protovis](https://github.com/mbostock/protovis)
- [Makefile](https://github.com/mbostock/topotree/blob/master/Makefile) for [topotree](https://github.com/mbostock/topotree)

Also look at the [Makefile](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/Makefile) for [Yihui Xie](http://yihui.name/)’s [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) package for [R](http://r-project.org/).

Also of interest is [maker](https://github.com/ComputationalProteomicsUnit/maker), a Makefile for R package development.

### Resources

- [GNU make webpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/make)
- [Official manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)
- O’Reilly [Managing projects with GNU make](http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/) book (part of the [Open Books project](http://oreilly.com/openbook/))
- [Software carpentry](http://software-carpentry.org/)’s [make tutorial](http://swcarpentry.github.io/make-novice/)
- [Mike Bostock](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/)’s “[Why Use Make](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/make/)”
- [GNU Make for reproducible data analysis](http://zmjones.com/make.html) by [Zachary Jones](http://zmjones.com/)
- [Makefiles for R/LaTeX project](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/makefiles/)s by [Rob Hyndman](http://robjhyndman.com/)

---

## R package primer

### a minimal tutorial

#### A minimal tutorial on how to make an R package.

R packages are the best way to distribute R code and documentation,
and, despite the impression that the official manual
([Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html))
might give, they really are quite simple to create.

You should make an R package even for code that you don't plan to
distribute. You'll find it is easier to keep track of your own
personal R functions if they are in a package. And it's good to write
documentation, even if it's just for your future self.

[Hadley Wickham](http://had.co.nz/) wrote
[a book about R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) (free online; also
available in paper form from
[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491910593)). You
might just jump straight there.

[Hilary Parker](http://hilaryparker.com) wrote a
[short and clear tutorial on writing R packages](http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/).
If you want a crash course, you should start there. A lot of people
have successfully built R packages from her instructions.

But there is value in having a diversity of
resources, so I thought I'd go ahead and write my own minimal tutorial.
The following list of topics looks forbidding, but each is short and
straightforward (and hopefully clear). If you're put off by the list
of topics,
and you've not already abandoned me in favor of
[Hadley's book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/), then why aren't you reading
[Hilary's tutorial](http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/)?

If anyone's still with me, the following pages cover the essentials of
making an R package.

- [Why write an R package?](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/why.md)
- [The minimal R package](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/minimal.md)
- [Building and installing an R package](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/build.md)
- [Making it a proper package](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/proper.md)
- [Writing documentation with Roxygen2](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/docs.md)
- [Software licenses](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/licenses.md)
- [Checking an R package](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/check.md)

The following are important but not essential.

- [Putting it on GitHub](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/github.md)
- [Getting it on CRAN](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/cran.md)
- [Writing vignettes](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/vignettes.md)
- [Writing tests](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/tests.md)
- [Including datasets](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/data.md)
- [Connecting to other packages](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/depends.md)

The following contains links to other resources:

- [Further resources](https://github.com/Technophobe01/pkg_primer/blob/gh-pages/pages/resources.md)

If anything here is confusing (or *wrong*!), or if I've missed
important details, please
[submit an issue](https://github.com/kbroman/pkg_primer/issues), or (even
better) fork [the GitHub repository for this website](http://github.com/kbroman/pkg_primer),
make modifications, and submit a pull request.

---

The source for this tutorial is [on github](http://github.com/kbroman/pkg_primer).

Also see my [tutorials](http://kbroman.org/pages/tutorials) on
[git/github](http://kbroman.org/github_tutorial),
[GNU make](http://kbroman.org/minimal_make),
[knitr](http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell),
[making a web site with GitHub Pages](http://kbroman.org/simple_site),
[data organization](http://kbroman.org/dataorg),
and [reproducible research](http://kbroman.org/steps2rr).

Comment: Long answer ;) need to do some thinking.  Yihuis makefile seems close to what I intend - but there are things that I wouldn't consider good practice - like building files in the parent directory and deleting there, using sed to figure out the target name.

Comment: @bdecaf - Chuckle - A bit of a data broadside. ;-) My sense was to provide the background materials in the answer rather than by reference as some of the materials are old (though hopefully useful). I hope it helps - Take care T.

Comment: Could you clarify one bit - when you build qtlchart - do you use `R CMD build` or `make` or some other combination of commands?

Comment: @bdecaf The preferred way to invoke the build is to 1) `git clone https://github.com/kbroman/qtlcharts.git` 2) Invoke R 3) invoke `library(devtools)`, 4) `install_local("qtlcharts")`. If you look at the code for `devtools::install_local()` that will show you the steps. `https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/install-local.r`

Comment: i.e. `R --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  './qtlcharts'  \
  --library='/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.2/lib/R/library' --install-tests`

Comment: Thank you for being so patient.  I did have a look at these commands already - but maybe I had something malformed. Taking qtlcharts as working example I was particularly looking for the ToDo.html from the Makefile and could not locate it (but ToDo.md was at the expected location). So do I see this correctly that the Makefile is not involved when building a package?

Comment: @bdecaf The `Makefile` is definitely invoked. If you look at the top of the `Makefile` you will see the list of targets. For example, if you type `make doc` it will launch `R -e 'devtools::document()'; if you type `make inst/ToDo.html` it will launch R and invoke `markdown::markdownToHTML("ToDo.md", "ToDo.html")`.

Comment: @bdecaf Did that help clarify the situation with the makefile? Just checking you are all good. Hope things are well.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure things out, I started a package and put some of my notes [there](https://github.com/bdcaf/vignetteEngineMake) in case you are interested.

Comment: But could you have a look at this: Taking qlcharts as example, freshly cloned with `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/kbroman/qtlcharts.git` and immediately do `R CMD build qtlcharts`. As I understand it should be build completely including running the Makefile. But when I inspect the produced tar file I can not locate e.g. `inst/ToDo.html` or any `ToDo.html`. Downloading the package from CRAN I also can't locate it. Do you have some special setup to create it?